# Maven plugin jsonschema2pojo returns ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven

I need to generate java pojos from JSON schema. I'm trying to use jsonschema2pojo maven plugin for this purpose. I wrote custom rule factory and I want to use it for pojos generation.
Here is my jsonschema2pojo plugin configuration:

```
       <plugin>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-artifact-id</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateClassesFromSchema</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas</sourceDirectory>
                <targetPackage>my.target.package</targetPackage>
                <includeHashcodeAndEquals>false</includeHashcodeAndEquals>
                <customRuleFactory>path.to.rule.factory.MyCustomRuleFactory</customRuleFactory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**MyCustomRuleFactory.java** is the part of my project, dependency for which is inside plugin element. But when a do mvn clean install I get thi following:

`Failed to execute goal org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:1.1.1:generate (generateClassesFromSchema) on project my-artifact-id: Execution generateClassesFromSchema of goal org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:1.1.1:generate failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: path.to.rule.factory.MyCustomRuleFactory`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand in the tag "customRuleFactory" must be full class name. Are you sure you didn't add path?

`path.to.rule.factory.MyCustomRuleFactory`
May be correct `rule.factory.MyCustomRuleFactory`